# How do you know what packages/ nodes to be installed if you download from source

Tags: ros, hector-slam, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a general question about what steps to take in order to compile code from source.

So I have currently installed hector slam from https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam and I am confused on catkin_make process in order to compile the code.
There are a lot of make errors that I am encountering, so please provide some direction on how to go about this and the next steps.

Thanks You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256599/how-do-you-know-what-packages/-nodes-to-be-installed-if-you-download-from-source/) by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Best way to install all requires dependencies is to use `rosdep`.

For a source workspace, the typical command is:

```
rosdep install --from-paths PATH/TO/SRC -i
```

the `-i` switch does not install dependencies that are in the source path.

Note, rosdep install all the debian packages, it does not download anything from source. So if you have dependencies to repos that are not released, you still need to do the manual fiddeling and resolving of those dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0